# How can we enter time in input field with format HH:MM and also include validation

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, user-input, angular16

I was using [@julianobrasil/timemask](https://github.com/julianobrasil/lib-time-mask) library for formatting the input value in Angular 15, when I updated the application to Angular 16 the library [@julianobrasil/timemask](https://github.com/julianobrasil/lib-time-mask) is not supported in the updated application.

Is there any other library or way to enter time in an input field with HH:MM format and validation?

I want to find a new way to enter the time in an input field with format HH:MM and also include validation.

Comment: I might use two `<select>` elements: one for the the hours and one for the minutes.